# Highchart not showing on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, highcharts, smartphone

I have a issue with my charts working in highcharts.

All my charts are displaying correctly on desktop , in Chrome/FF/IE/Safari

But when i'm on mobile, any of them are showing.
I have nothing on my log so I would like to know how can i fix them,

There is the link for the charts :
http://www.chahinecapital.com/fonds/

You can go on the sub heading `Digital Star Europe` , and click the button for `ACTIFS` as exemple.

There is also my `loadEurope.js` , where i initialize the charts

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
        months: [
            'Janvier', 'Février', 'Mars', 'Avril',
            'Mai', 'Juin', 'Juillet', 'Août',
            'Septembre', 'Octobre', 'Novembre', 'Décembre'
        ],
        weekdays: [
            'Dimanche', 'Lundi', 'Mardi', 'Mercredi',
            'Jeudi', 'Vendredi', 'Samedi'
        ],
        shortMonths: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Avr', 'Mai', 'Juin', 'Juil',
                      'Aout', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Déc'
        ]
    }
});



$.get('http://www.chahinecapital.com/wp-content/themes/consulting-child/data/fonds/DigitalStarsEurope/volatilityFR.csv', function(data) {
    $('#EuropeVolatility').highcharts({

          yAxis: [{

                labels: {
                    format: '{value} %',

                },
                title: {
                    text: ' ',  
                }

            }],
        data: {
          csv: data,
        },
        series: [{
            color: '#682666',
          }, {
            color: '#ed8322',
          },{
            color: '#B7ADA5',
             }],
        xAxis: {
            tickPixelInterval: 50,
        },
        title:{
            text:null
        }
      });
    });




$("#EuropeAllocPaysBtn").click(function() {
$.get("http://www.chahinecapital.com/wp-content/themes/consulting-child/data/fonds/DigitalStarsEurope/countryFR.csv", function(csv) {
    $('#EuropeAllocPays').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'pie',
            options3d: {
                enabled: true,
                alpha: 45,
                beta: 0
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
             pie: {
                 allowPointSelect: true,
                 cursor: 'pointer',
                 depth: 35,
                 dataLabels: {
                     enabled: false
                 },
                 showInLegend: true
             }
         },
        data: {
            csv: csv
        },
        title:{
            text:null
        }
    });
});
});


$("#EuropeAllocSecteursBtn").click(function() {
    $.get("http://www.chahinecapital.com/wp-content/themes/consulting-child/data/fonds/DigitalStarsEurope/secteursFR.csv", function(csv) {
        $('#EuropeAllocSecteurs').highcharts({
             chart: {

                 type: 'pie',
                 options3d: {
                     enabled: true,
                     alpha: 45,
                     beta: 0
                 }
             },
             plotOptions: {
                 pie: {
                     allowPointSelect: true,
                     cursor: 'pointer',
                     depth: 35,
                     dataLabels: {
                         enabled: false
                        },
                     showInLegend: true
                    }
             },
            data: {
                csv: csv
            },
            title:{
                text:null
            }
        });
    });
    });


$("#EuropeActifsBtn").click(function() {
    $.get("http://www.chahinecapital.com/wp-content/themes/consulting-child/data/fonds/DigitalStarsEurope/assetsFR.csv", function(csv) {
        $('#EuropeActifs').highcharts({

             yAxis: [{ 
                    gridLineWidth: 0,
                    labels: {
                        format: '{value:,.0f}',


                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Nombre de parts',  
                    },
                    opposite: true
                },
                { 
                    labels: {
                        format: '{value}',
                        formatter: function(){
                            return this.value/100000 + "M";
                          }

                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Actifs en \u20AC ',

                    }


                }],

            data: {
                csv: csv
            },
            series: [{
                yAxis:1,
                color: '#682666',
              }, {
                yAxis:0,
                color: '#ed8322',
              }],
              title:{
                    text:null
                }
        });
    });
});



$("#EuropePerformancesPeriodeBtn").click(function() {
    $.get("http://www.chahinecapital.com/wp-content/themes/consulting-child/data/fonds/DigitalStarsEurope/performancesFR.csv", function(csv) {
        $('#EuropePerformancesPeriode').highcharts({
            yAxis: [{
                labels: {
                    format: '{value} %',

                },
                title: {
                    text: ' ',  
                }

            }],
            xAxis:{
                tickInterval:1,
            },
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },

            data: {
                csv: csv
            },
            series: [{
                color: '#682666',
              }, {
                color: '#ed8322',
              },{
                color: '#B7ADA5',
                 }],
                 title:{
                        text:null
                    }
        });
    });
 });
});
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Jordan

Comment: From what I checked, while remote debugging your page from a mobile device, the container (#EuropeActifs) for a chart is present but it is empty (the chart is not even added). In desktop version charts are added correctly.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. How can my chart not be added, if in desktop I added....I don't understand...
When you do the remot debug ( i don't know how to achieve this ) did Jquery load ?

Comment: Hi , I was able to do the remote debbuging, not easy ;-) 
But i can saw that Jquery is correctly call...
So may be another solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I went through this exact same problem with another library, so I will put an answer here, maybe it will help someone.

Just to be clear, my problem was with **AM4CHARTS** library.

All charts working fine in Desktop, even when I was setting chrome and firefox to mobile mode, but not showing in Mobile.

The issue in my case was, for some reason, the **browser cache**.

I did clean the cache for the last 24 hours at chrome in android, and the charts went back.

Hope this helps anyone who might step into this.